# How do I make the bootstrap carousel scale properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a bootstrap carousel and noticed on mobile and smaller screens, the images just look really "skinny". I know this is part of the responsiveness, but I've seen on some sites where the carousel maintains it's original aspect ratio and just scales to a smaller carousel.

How can I do this with my code?

https://jsfiddle.net/nv7rsgpg/9/share

It seems when I change height: 100vh to auto, it works, but then every time I click the arrow buttons the height of course constantly keeps changing depending on the size of them.

```
    <!-- Navigation -->
<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
<nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <li class="sidebar-brand">
            <a href="#top"  onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Start Bootstrap</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#top" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#about" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#services" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#portfolio" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact" onclick = $("#menu-close").click(); >Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<header>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/cats" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/abstract" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/transportation" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</header>


<!-- About -->
<section id="about" class="about">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>

        </ol>
        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Services -->
<!-- The circle icons use Font Awesome's stacked icon classes. For more information, visit http://fontawesome.io/examples/ -->
<section id="services" class="services bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                <h2>Our Services</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-compass fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-flask fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="service-item">
                            <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">
                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                            <i class="fa fa-shield fa-stack-1x text-primary"></i>
                        </span>
                            <h4>
                                <strong>Service Name</strong>
                            </h4>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-light">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Callout -->
<aside class="callout">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">
        <h1>Vertically Centered Text</h1>
    </div>
</aside>

<!-- Portfolio -->
<section id="portfolio" class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Our Work</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-1.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="img/portfolio-4.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-dark">View More Items</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</section>

<!-- Call to Action -->
<aside class="call-to-action bg-primary">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h3>The buttons below are impossible to resist.</h3>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-light">Click Me!</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Look at Me!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>

<!-- Map -->
<section id="contact" class="map">
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
    <br />
    <small>
        <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=twitter&amp;sll=28.659344,-81.187888&amp;sspn=0.128789,0.264187&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Twitter,+Inc.,+Market+Street,+San+Francisco,+CA&amp;t=m&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=A"></a>
    </small>
    </iframe>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h4><strong>Start Bootstrap</strong>
                </h4>
                <p>3481 Melrose Place<br>Beverly Hills, CA 90210</p>
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw"></i> (123) 456-7890</li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>  <a href="mailto:name@example.com">name@example.com</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble fa-fw fa-3x"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr class="small">
                <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>



// Closes the sidebar menu
$("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

// Opens the sidebar menu
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});

// Scrolls to the selected menu item on the page
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#]):not([href=#myCarousel]):not([href="#myCarousel2])"').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});




.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }

.vcenter {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.v-center {
    position: absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:40%;
    top:50%;
    bottom:50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    left:15%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the `.img-responsive` class to your images and let bootstrap scale them accordingly.

So your image tag will look like:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
```

You can do this for all images.

Responsive images automatically adjust to fit the size of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply `height: 100vh;` you are applying certain height to all images. So carousel heights remains same. But when you apply `height: auto;` then carousel uses original height of the image.

Another thing that I noticed is , you are applying `width: 100%;` to every carousel image. If image is of less dimensions, it will loose its quality.

Better approach would be to keep he auto and use images of correct dimensions.

Comment: But I would like to keep the height 100vh because it scales to fit the entire screen no matter the resolution, which creates that nice, big "jumbo tron cover" look. Say I did want the images to maintain a set height and width (without having to manually resize my images), how would I do that?